# Local variables captured by a lambda expression?

Tags: c#

I'm reading a book which says:

> Local variables captured by a lambda expression or anonymous delegate are converted by the compiler into fields, and so can also be shared:

```
class ThreadTest
{
    static void Main()
    {
       bool done = false;
       ThreadStart action = () =>
       {
           if (!done) { done = true; Console.WriteLine ("Done"); }
       };
       new Thread (action).Start();
       action();
    }

    /*
    void TestField() 
    {
       bool b = done; //error cannot reference `done`
    }
    */
}
```

but if the compiler has converted `done` into a field, then why I am unable to access it in another method `TestField`?

Comment: i think because `done` is in the scope of `Action` delegate(which behaves the same as "normal" inside function parameters )

Comment: The field isn't generated for the ThreadTest class, but instead for the class container of the lambda function https://medium.com/@unicorn_dev/how-to-capture-a-variable-in-c-and-not-to-shoot-yourself-in-the-foot-d169aa161aa6

Comment: What happen if `Main()` is not `static`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use a tool like [this](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgDABFAjAOgCoAsBOBTAhsASwDsBzAbgFgAoKAJkWurrgx31WwGcAXagb2pwhCRADYEAFjgBZXMQAUASkHCBVYRoBGAe20AbOMG1FscALxwAZrj2dsldRqGs8wAMrdcmbnFwBjbgJjczglcwA+FSc1J1iCS1CAQiMTRTg+Q2NTC25MAFd7EQBOUIAiABEs0sUyOABfKI06h1i4EwB3FixXUP9A40VkDy9uJRbYvqCiMcaGqkaAegAqRqgpDh4AMQJsPWAwxpjYnX04TRCUwoWF7ExMbUw4P1wiIm0fHEtb7CI/UwADS7/WaNJYLah1IA) one:

You will notice that when your code is compiled a *compiler generated class* is generated and the `done` is declared as a field of this class:

```
[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public bool done;

    internal void <Main>b__0()
    {
        if (!done)
        {
            done = true;
            Console.WriteLine("Done");
        }
    }
}
```

So you **can't** access that field via your code. The `done` is not defined as a class field of `ThreadTest` class but as a field in the compiler generated class. Later on, it is used in your Main method as below:

```
private static void Main()
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.done = false;
    ThreadStart threadStart = new ThreadStart(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<Main>b__0);
    new Thread(threadStart).Start();
    threadStart();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No question is dumb, except the question that is not asked.  Some of the other answers give more technical information, but as you say you are new to C#, I thought a simpler explanation may be helpful.

In C#, variable scope is (effectively) defined by curly braces.

In your code, `done` is defined in the `Main()` method, so it's available to everything *inside* that method, including lambda functions like `action`.

If you defined another variable `x` *inside* the `action` lambda, it would be available to everything *inside* that lambda, but not `Main()`.

The same is true for conditional statements. If you declare a variable inside an `if` block, it is available to everything *inside* that block, but not the calling method.

This is why `done` is not available to `TestField()`, because `TestField()` is not defined *inside* `Main()`.

Answer (score 0):

That is some unfortunate wording. Forget about that sentence for a second and let's talk about **scopes**.

Simplifying, we can assume that a local variable is *in scope* in the entire block that encloses it.

```
void Foo()
{
  var x; // x is in scope now

  if (...)
  {
      var y; // y is in scope now
      
      ...
  } // y exits scope

} // x exits scope
```

This is not how it works *exactly*, but it's a useful model. In the above code, referring to `y` outside of the `if` block is an error, since there is no `y` in scope.

This should be enough to explain why your code doesn't work. The `done` variable is in scope for the entirety of the `Main` method, but it's not in scope in `TestField`.

The author of the statement is most likely trying to convey the semantics of **closures**. Anonymous functions create closures and can capture variables from the enclosing scope. What that means is that for example this code:

```
void Foo()
{
    var x = 0;

    Action inc = () => { x += 1; };
    Action print = () => { Console.WriteLine(x); };

    print();
    inc();
    print();
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

will print

```
0
1
1
```

The local variable `x` is *captured* by both lambdas assigned to `inc` and `print` and is shared between them. The fun part of this is that captured variables can "escape scope":

```
static (Action inc, Action print) Foo()
{
    var x = 0;
    Action inc = () => { x += 1; };
    Action print = () => { Console.WriteLine(x); };

    return (inc, print);
}

static void Main()
{
    var (inc, print) = Foo();

    inc();
    inc();
    print(); // Prints 2.
}
```

Here the `x` variable lives longer than its scope, since it has to be accessible from the lambda functions even after the `Foo` method returns.

To solve the puzzle of the "field" part of your quote we must ask ourselves how the compiler achieves that. Here's how:

```
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int x;

    internal void <>b__2()
    {
        x++;
    }

    internal void <>b__3()
    {
       Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}

static (Action inc, Action print) Foo()
{
    <>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new <>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.x = 0;

    Action inc = new Action(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<>b__2);
    Action print = new Action(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<>b__3);
    return (item, item2);
}

static void Main()
{
    (inc, print) = Foo();
    inc();
    inc();
    print();
}
```

This is more-less what the compiler generates. The `<>c__DisplayClass0_` is a class generated for the anonymous functions. Its name is not expressible in valid C#. As you can see, the local variable is converted into a field in the class, anonymous functions become methods of that class and they both reference the same shared field.

So you cannot normally access that field from different scopes (thank goodness you can't, that would enable some real nasty spaghetti!), unless you start invoking reflection and other dark magic.